# In Julia: How to declare the type of a function parameter that is a function?

Tags: julia

When I have a function that takes another function as parameter, how can I declare the type of that function?

For example, I have a function `f` that takes two integers and a function `g` that combines those integers and returns an integer:

```
function f(a::Int, b::Int, g)::Int
  g(a, b)
end
```

How can I declare the type of `g` in this case? I tried things like `::(Int, Int)->Int` which does not work (sorry, did not find it in the docs).

Comment: You can't do that, why do you need it? You can, however, add a type assert at the call to `g`, something like: `g(a, b)::Int` which will error in case `g` does not return an `Int`.

Comment: All functions have their own type, so the type of `sin` is `typeof(sin)`. There's also an abstract supertype, `Function`. So you can declare `g::Function`, or e.g. `g::typeof(sin)`. Functions don't have types describing their input and output argument types, since each function can have arbitrarily many methods, which each have different input and output types.

Comment: AFAIK, it is still currently not possible but you can specify the (output) type for `g` (If the output type of actual `g` is not convertible to the output type you specified it will return an error). What is your use case? I do not think one usually needs this feature in Julia.  It will not give you any better performance.

Comment: Thank you all. My use case was just readability; just to see what kind of function I can pass to another function. Attaching the type to the function call (`g(a, b)::Int`) is nice.

Comment: I meant not the function call but the function definiton: `function g(a::Int, b:Int)::Int ...` And then in your function `function f(a::Int, b::Int, g::Int)::Int ...`

Comment: I doubt I'd ever do this, but if you had to, you could create a shell function to check the return type: function f(x) return x end;  function wrapf(x) = f(x)::Int